# Is there support for EJS files in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: ejs, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, and I would like syntax highlighting and checking support for .ejs files.  All search results for this appear to be related to Visual Studio Code.

At the very least is it possible for Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 to treat .ejs files as HTML?

Answer (score 0):

click tools > options > texteditor:file extension and type ejs into extension, then select html editor from the select and click add. I do not know how to get it to actually see the javascript as code, though.